# Faster way to process 1.2 million JSON geolocation queries from large dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, geolocation

I am working on the [Gowalla location-based checkin dataset](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/loc-gowalla.html) which has around 6.44 million checkins. Unique locations on these checkins are 1.28 million. But Gowalla only gives latitudes and longitudes. So I need to find city, state and country for each of those lats and longs. From another post on StackOverflow I was able to create the R query below which queries the open street maps and finds the relevant geographical details.

Unfortunately it takes around 1 minute to process 125 rows, which means 1.28 million rows would take a couple of days. Is there a faster way to find these details? Maybe there is some package with builtin lats and longs of cities of the world to find the city name for the given lat and long so I do not have to do online querying.

Venue table is a data frame with 3 columns: `1: vid(venueId), 2 lat(latitude), 3: long(longitude)`

```
for(i in 1:nrow(venueTable)) {
 #this is just an indicator to display current value of i on screen
 cat(paste(".",i,".")) 

 #Below code composes the url query 
 url <- paste("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php? format=json&lat=",
              venueTableTest3$lat[i],"&lon=",venueTableTest3$long[i])
 url <- gsub(' ','',url)
 url <- paste(url)
 x <- fromJSON(url)
 venueTableTest3$display_name[i] <- x$display_name
 venueTableTest3$country[i] <- x$address$country
}
```

I am using the `jsonlite` package in R which makes `x` which is the result of the JSON query as a dataframe which stores various results returned. So using `x$display_name` or `x$address$city` i use my required field.

My laptop is core i5 3230M with 8gb ram and 120gb SSD using Windows 8.

Comment: Not sure how to do that in R, but I think your code is synchronous, meaning that only 1 HTTP request is sent at a time. If you'd be able to send like 10 at once, you may get ~5x faster speeds.

Comment: Your question has a builtin assumption that you need to make an API call for each 1.28m distinct location, just because the SO solution you looked at did. But offline lookup is better. You might like to edit your question to separate the assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have issues even if you persevere with time. The service you're querying allows 'an absolute maximum of one request per second', which you're already breaching. It's likely that they will throttle your requests before you reach 1.2m queries. Their website notes similar APIs for larger uses have only around 15k free daily requests.

It'd be much better for you to use an offline option. A quick search shows that there are many freely available datasets of populated places, along with their longitude and latitudes. Here's one we'll use: http://simplemaps.com/resources/world-cities-data

```
> library(dplyr)

> cities.data <- read.csv("world_cities.csv") %>% tbl_df
> print(cities.data)

Source: local data frame [7,322 x 9]

             city     city_ascii     lat     lng    pop     country   iso2   iso3 province
           (fctr)         (fctr)   (dbl)   (dbl)  (dbl)      (fctr) (fctr) (fctr)   (fctr)
1   Qal eh-ye Now      Qal eh-ye 34.9830 63.1333   2997 Afghanistan     AF    AFG  Badghis
2     Chaghcharan    Chaghcharan 34.5167 65.2500  15000 Afghanistan     AF    AFG     Ghor
3     Lashkar Gah    Lashkar Gah 31.5830 64.3600 201546 Afghanistan     AF    AFG  Hilmand
4          Zaranj         Zaranj 31.1120 61.8870  49851 Afghanistan     AF    AFG   Nimroz
5      Tarin Kowt     Tarin Kowt 32.6333 65.8667  10000 Afghanistan     AF    AFG  Uruzgan
6    Zareh Sharan   Zareh Sharan 32.8500 68.4167  13737 Afghanistan     AF    AFG  Paktika
7        Asadabad       Asadabad 34.8660 71.1500  48400 Afghanistan     AF    AFG    Kunar
8         Taloqan        Taloqan 36.7300 69.5400  64256 Afghanistan     AF    AFG   Takhar
9  Mahmud-E Eraqi Mahmud-E Eraqi 35.0167 69.3333   7407 Afghanistan     AF    AFG   Kapisa
10     Mehtar Lam     Mehtar Lam 34.6500 70.1667  17345 Afghanistan     AF    AFG  Laghman
..            ...            ...     ...     ...    ...         ...    ...    ...      ...
```

It's hard to demonstrate without any actual data examples (helpful to provide!), but we can make up some toy data.

```
# make up toy data
> candidate.longlat <- data.frame(vid = 1:3, 
                                lat = c(12.53, -16.31, 42.87), 
                                long = c(-70.03, -48.95, 74.59))
```

Using the `distm` function in `geosphere`, we can calculate the distances between all your data and all the city locations at once. For you, this will make a `matrix` containing ~8,400,000,000 numbers, so it might take a while (can explore parallisation), and may be highly memory intensive.

```
> install.packages("geosphere")
> library(geosphere)

# compute distance matrix using geosphere
> distance.matrix <- distm(x = candidate.longlat[,c("long", "lat")], 
                         y = cities.data[,c("lng", "lat")])
```

It's then easy to find the closest city to each of your data points, and `cbind` it to your `data.frame`.

```
# work out which index in the matrix is closest to the data
> closest.index <- apply(distance.matrix, 1, which.min)

# rbind city and country of match with original query
> candidate.longlat <- cbind(candidate.longlat, cities.data[closest.index, c("city", "country")])
> print(candidate.longlat)

  vid    lat   long       city    country
1   1  12.53 -70.03 Oranjestad      Aruba
2   2 -16.31 -48.95   Anapolis     Brazil
3   3  42.87  74.59    Bishkek Kyrgyzstan
```

Comment: That is some explanation! Thanks a lot for such a detailed response.

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks a ton.

Comment: which distance function does does `distm` use by default when a distance function has not been specified?

Comment: Haversine. You can specify within the function, see the documentation.

Comment: I tried executing your code in chunks of 5k rows upto the point where I got an error from R for memory exceeding. So i went upto 20k rows at a time. Surprisingly it only takes 2 minutes for matrix generation for 20k rows and make the matrix size of 1.2gb that way 1.2mil rows would only take 2 hours roughly for matrix generation. That is tons of time saved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate way using R's inherent spatial processing capabilities:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)

# world places shapefile
URL1 <- "http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_populated_places.zip"
fil1 <- basename(URL1)
if (!file.exists(fil1)) download.file(URL1, fil1)
unzip(fil1)

places <- readOGR("ne_10m_populated_places.shp", "ne_10m_populated_places",
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# some data from the other answer since you didn't provide any
URL2 <- "http://simplemaps.com/resources/files/world/world_cities.csv"
fil2 <- basename(URL2)
if (!file.exists(fil2)) download.file(URL2, fil2)

# we need the points from said dat
dat <- read.csv(fil2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
pts <- SpatialPoints(dat[,c("lng", "lat")], CRS(proj4string(places)))

# this is not necessary
# I just don't like the warning about longlat not being a real projection
robin <- "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
pts <- spTransform(pts, robin)
places <- spTransform(places, robin)

# compute the distance (makes a pretty big matrix so you should do this
# in chunks unless you have a ton of memory or do it row-by-row
far <- gDistance(pts, places, byid=TRUE)

# find the closest one
closest <- apply(far, 1, which.min)

# map to the fields (you may want to map to other fields)
locs <- places@data[closest, c("NAME", "ADM1NAME", "ISO_A2")]

locs[sample(nrow(locs), 10),]

##              NAME        ADM1NAME ISO_A2
## 3274     Szczecin West Pomeranian     PL
## 1039     Balakhna      Nizhegorod     RU
## 1012       Chitre         Herrera     PA
## 3382     L'Aquila         Abruzzo     IT
## 1982       Dothan         Alabama     US
## 5159 Bayankhongor     Bayanhongor     MN
## 620        Deming      New Mexico     US
## 1907   Fort Smith        Arkansas     US
## 481      Dedougou        Mou Houn     BF
## 7169       Prague          Prague     CZ
```

It's about a minute (on my system) for ~7500 so you're looking at a couple hours vs a day or more. You can do this in parallel and prbly get it done in less than an hour.

For better place resolution, you could use a very lightweight shapefile of country or Admin 1 polygons, then use a second process to do the distance from better resolution points for those geographic locations.